# trigger radioButton change event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to change radio button selection in a radio group that uses a for loop? I want to use the changeRadio method to select (and trigger the change) the radio button based on a received value.

```
<mat-radio-group (change)="onHobbyChange()">
      <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies" [value]="hobby.favorite">
      </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

changeRadio(value){
    const event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
    this.matRadioButton._inputElement.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

I tried with _inputElement but it seems to select allways the first element and do not tigger the change event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use ngModel or formControl you could use component variable

see this example: [Full code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgmhhc?file=src/app/radio-ng-model-example.ts)

```
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  favoriteSeason: string;
  seasons: string[] = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];

  whenSeasonChange() {
    this.favoriteSeason = 'Summer';
  }

  onSeasonChange(event: any) {
    this.favoriteSeason = event.value;
  }
}

<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite season</label>
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  (change)="onSeasonChange($event)"
>
  <mat-radio-button
    class="example-radio-button"
    *ngFor="let season of seasons"
    [value]="season"
    [checked]="season === favoriteSeason"
  >
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>

<button (click)="whenSeasonChange()">Click to be Summer</button>
```